# Rails 3 localized routes and show resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, internationalization, routes

I'm rewriting my routes on a Rails 3.2 server, so the language is a part of the URL. My routes.rb file is like that:

```
scope ":lang", :lang => /es|fr|it|pt|en|de/ do
    resources :users
end
```

Pretty much all URLs work perfectly by appending the language strings, i.e:

```
http://mydomain/es/somecontroller/someaction
```

The problem comes with the show actions, the links doesn't work. This line:

```
<%= link_to "Show", @my_user %>
```

Causes a "Routing Error" like this:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :lang=>##User serialization##}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Ok, **solution found**. Thanks to Cage and a little research there's the solution.

Only need a method on ApplicationController like this:

```
def self.default_url_options
  { :lang => FastGettext.locale }
end
```

And everything works flawlessly!! No need to rewrite links at all.

Comment: Correction: all the links with an :id doesn't work, like edit and destroy ones. Only new and index work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For show, edit, destroy you should be passing :id of the object in path else it will show an error. For e.g.

```
 <%= link_to "Show", user_path(@my_user.id) %>
```

Go through this link it will help you a lot in case of routing http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Now the error is different: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :lang=>6} (6 is the user id). Thanks anyway

Comment: then in user_path try to pass the language you want to work with.

Comment: This works, thanks again, but involves changing about 100+ links all over the site, really not any other way? more automatic?, maybe a link_to re-definition?

Comment: I am not aware of any other way sorry.

Comment: This solution also faults on form_for, so it's more complicated than I thought...

Comment: I am not sure if issue with form_for is related to routing.

Comment: It gives pretty much the same error, and when I set the form differently it don't give the error, but breaks the submit button.

Comment: in form_for the path you are giving it is a 'POST' method you don't have to pass anything in that